# Updating styles of a styled-component on props change slow?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, delay, styled-components

In my parent component i have a onScroll Listener that determines whether i hit a specific point when scrolling. There is a boolean stored in the state. I pass this state variable down to a child. In that child i have a styled component that changes with the boolean state variable that was passed down as props. When i scroll really fast the css seems to change very slow. Is there anyway to speed this up?

Parent Component:

```
 class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var test = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test);
    test.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    if (test.scrollTop = 10) {
      this.setState({
        flag: true
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        flag: false
      })
    };
  }
  render() { 
    return (
      <Component ref="test" >
      <Child flag={
        this.state.flag
      }/> 
      </Component>
    )
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
const Container = styled.div`
     height: ${({flag})=>flag ? "10px" : "50px"}
`;

....
....
....

render(){
  <Container flag={this.props.flag}/>
}
```

that is a very basic idea of what im doing in general, when i scroll really fast past the point of trigger it takes a slight second before rendering. Is there anyway i can avoid this delay and speed things up. Or is there a better way you guys recommend doing this.

Comment: test isn’t declared in handleScroll but you are doing condition check with that

Answer (score 0):

In `handleScroll` method, you doesn't declare test. You should do like the following:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var test = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test);
    test.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = (event) => {
    if (event.scrollTop = 10) {
      this.setState({
        flag: true
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        flag: false
      })
    };
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <Component ref="test">
        <Child flag={
          this.state.flag
        }/> 
      </Component>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: event is undefined if you do this

Comment: Also this doesn't fix the rendering issue, there is still a delay with the css changes when scrolling fast.

Comment: The problem is the eventlistener takes a while to execute when scrolling fast because it has to keep up.